# Pointless ternary operator being used in this statement

Tags: c

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

I have this function that assigns a pointer to an another pointer that is an element of a string structure.

The purpose of this string structure is to get and set the length of the actual string.

However, I don't understand why they have used a ternary operator. It doesn't make sense to me. There doesn't seem to be a condition apart from `str->len = src`. Which only assigns and doesn't compare anything.

```
typedef struct tag_str_t str_t;
struct tag_str_t {
    char *buf;
    size_t len;
};

static void string_set(str_t *str, const char *src)
{
    str->buf = (char*)src;
    str->len = src ? strlen(src) : 0;
}
```

Would it be just as simple and more readable by doing just this?

```
str->len = strlen(src);
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code:

```
str->len = src ? strlen(src) : 0;
```

is equivalent to:

```
str->len = ((src != 0) ? strlen(src) : 0);
```

I've added the parentheses and the extra expression to indicate where the components of the expression are.  Your comment seems to indicate that you think `str->len = src` is the condition in the ternary operator, but that is wrong; assignment has a very low precedence.

As [Jesus Ramos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392046/jesus-ramos) also [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14353333/15168), the purpose of the test is to ensure that `strlen()` is not called with a NULL pointer, which would lead to a crash.

Comment: Thanks, the penny finally dropped. Normally I always wrap my condition in brackets to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `strlen(NULL)` will generate a segfault, that code simply says if the src string is NULL the length is zero, if not calculate the length using `strlen`.

Comment: @alk True, I don't know of an implementation where it will as NULL space on many architectures now covers a big enough range or unless strlen does a NULL check (which from what I can see in the code it does not).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, its like this str->len = (src != NULL) ? strlen(src) : 0;

Comment: @ant2009 Yes that's correct. Normal values in C can evaluate to boolean expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The Ternary Operator is used there not to compare but to check for `src`. Assume if you pass `NULL` as `src`, then the code will invoke `Undefined Behavior`. So, the ternary operator checks as:

```
if( src != NULL )
    str->len = strlen(src) ; 
else
    str->len = 0 ;
```

Comment: Not so much _may exhibit undefined behaviour_ as _does invoke undefined behaviour_.  Calling a library function with a null pointer that is not expressly permitted invokes undefined behaviour, and `strlen()` is not documented as accepting a null pointer, so calling it with a null pointer invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler- Thanks for the clarification. This is what I love about SO, people can learn in so many ways here :-)